# How to discover php COM class

Tags: php, class, methods, com, ms-word

I want to do some stuff in some ms word documents using PHP (mostly search-replace), and I've discovered the COM class. But I have a question (because I'm also relative new on PHP), how can I found all methods related to word for example:

```
$objBookmark = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks($bookmarkname);
$range = $objBookmark->Range;
```

How should I now about ActiveDocument, Bookmarks, Range...etc. Is there any way to have a list with all this?

Answer (score 0):

To have autocomplete (InteliSense) you need a PHP class model and a good IDE. This will make your work much much easier.

One of the best IDE's I have come acrross is PHP Tools for Visual Studio. Look for it in the Visual Studio plugin gallery or in the Devsense website. You can use Visual Studio for FREE with the community edition.

To generate a PHP based class model you can either use the COM built in function:

com_print_typeinfo ( object $comobject [, string $dispinterface [, bool $wantsink = false ]] )

Or the NetPhp component (this link is to a step by step example with Word Interop) that will dump all types inside the binary to a complete PHP based class model:

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/php-com-class-consuming-net-php

You can also use NetPhp to directly consume the OpenXML binaries and manipulate Word documents without Interop:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/994905/Edit-Word-Documents-using-OpenXML-and-Csharp-Witho